# value of $1+\frac{1}{1+2}+\frac{1}{1+2+3}+\frac{1}{1+2+3+4}+\frac{1}{1+2+3+4+5}+\cdots$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is there anything known about the value of the series $1+\frac{1}{1+2}+\frac{1}{1+2+3}+\frac{1}{1+2+3+4}+\frac{1}{1+2+3+4+5}+\frac{1}{1+2+3+4+5+6}+\cdots$ ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, in fact, everything is known about it. Step 1: get a formula for the denominators (I assume the 6th one is supposed to have a 6 in it, not stop at 5 like the 5th one). Step 2: apply partial fractions to get a telescoping series. Enjoy.

Comment: thanks! fixed the typo after the 5yh term.

Comment: It equals 2....

Comment: @Gerry I think the last word was meant to be "profit".

Answer (score 24):

The denominators $a_n$ are
$$
a_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n}k = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}
$$
so
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac1{a_n} =
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2}{n(n+1)} =
2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+1} \right) = 2
$$
If you don't have the resources to check this on a computer (out to infinity),
you will have your computer or calculator carry out the calculation for $n<N$.
You should then get a number near the partial sum
$$
s_N=\sum_{n=1}^{N-1} \frac1{a_n} = 2 \left( 1 - \frac{1}{N} \right),
$$
where whatever difference you find between the computer's answer and this expected answer will be the result of truncation or rounding errors due to the machine representation of each [floating point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) number (which usually involve binary mantissas as in [IEEE formats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008)) encountered along the way.

Comment: whats your email address please, im not smart enough to figure it out from your profile