# Does $1+\frac{1}{1^k+2^k}+\frac{1}{1^k+2^k+3^k}+\frac{1}{1^k+2^k+3^k+4^k}+\frac{1}{1^k+2^k+3^k+4^k+5^k}\cdots$ telescope?

Tags: sequences-and-series

after the post [$1+\frac{1}{1+2}+\frac{1}{1+2+3}+\frac{1}{1+2+3+4}+\frac{1}{1+2+3+4+5}+\cdots$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/107435/value-of-1-frac112-frac1123-frac11234-frac112345/107438#comment251399_107438), I had to ask

Can we telescope the series  $$1+\frac{1}{1^k+2^k}+\frac{1}{1^k+2^k+3^k}+\frac{1}{1^k+2^k+3^k+4^k}+\frac{1}{1^k+2^k+3^k+4^k+5^k}+\frac{1}{1^k+2^k+3^k+4^k+5^k+6^k}+\cdots$$ ?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a perfect answer, but a hint. In [sum of powers](http://go.helms-net.de/math/potenzsummen/potenzsummen_1.htm) I've a (a bit old) treatize on the Eulerian numbers, which allow, in connection with the binomial-coefficients, to express the sums-of-like-powers as polynomials. Inserting these in the denominators of your sum should allow to do partial sums like in your linked other question. Unfortunately, [sum of powers](http://go.helms-net.de/math/potenzsummen/potenzsummen_1.htm) is in german, but the formulae are so simple, that it should be evident, how to proceed on your own. Maybe the same can be found using the [wikipedia-article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_number)

Comment: What is unfortunate is my level of german not the article being in german.